# Accessing an array of random audio objects with a UIButton

Tags: ios, swift

***** Question update ***** I thought I had all of this stuff figured out, but ran into one more problem at the end. My question class (see below) accepts an Int as a parameter in order to define an "answer" property to a "question" object I am creating.

When I am in the view controller, I need to access this answer property in order to check it. in my checkAnswer function, (see the code in view controller below) I am subscripting a variable called questionNumber. I know this is incorrect, I'm trying to access this parameter called "correct answer" in the init of my "Question" class.

Am I going about this wrong?

Thanks a million for any help here.

****** previous question ********

I'm a newbie working on my first iOS app using Swift. I'm running into a problem when I try to make a UIButton press access a random array of sound files that are in the bundle. I added the files to my Project outline by creating folder references.

I set up a model with a "question" file that takes some parameters (not sure if I did this right...)

```
import Foundation

class Question {

var questionText: URL
var answer: Int

init(text: String, correctAnswer: Int){
    questionText = Bundle.main.url(forResource: text, withExtension: "m4a", subdirectory: "Sounds")!
    answer = correctAnswer

}


}
```

Then I made a "question bank" file to add some properties (namely an answer Int)

```
import AVFoundation
import Foundation

class QuestionBank {


var list = [Question]()

init(){

    // creating a quiz item and appending it to the list
    let item = Question(text: "13", correctAnswer: 0)

    // add question to the list of items
    list.append(item)

    //creating the quiz item inside the append function
    list.append(Question(text: "14", correctAnswer: 1))
    list.append(Question(text: "15", correctAnswer: 2))
    list.append(Question(text: "16", correctAnswer: 2))
    list.append(Question(text: "17", correctAnswer: 1))
    list.append(Question(text: "18", correctAnswer: 0))
    list.append(Question(text: "19", correctAnswer: 0))
    list.append(Question(text: "20", correctAnswer: 1))
    list.append(Question(text: "21", correctAnswer: 2))
    list.append(Question(text: "22", correctAnswer: 2))
    list.append(Question(text: "23", correctAnswer: 0))
    list.append(Question(text: "24", correctAnswer: 1))

}
```

}

I created a function in my View Controller that deals with the button press. I'm getting the error on the "try audioPlayer..." line that says "Cannot convert value of type'Question' to expected argument 'URL'

```
func playRandomSound() {


    let sound1URL = allQuestions.list[0].questionText
    let sound2URL = allQuestions.list[1].questionText
    let sound3URL = allQuestions.list[2].questionText
    let sound4URL = allQuestions.list[3].questionText
    let sound5URL = allQuestions.list[4].questionText
    let sound6URL = allQuestions.list[5].questionText
    let sound7URL = allQuestions.list[6].questionText
    let sound8URL = allQuestions.list[7].questionText
    let sound9URL = allQuestions.list[8].questionText
    let sound10URL = allQuestions.list[9].questionText
    let sound11URL = allQuestions.list[10].questionText
    let sound12URL = allQuestions.list[11].questionText

    let soundURLArray = [sound1URL, sound2URL, sound3URL, sound4URL, sound5URL, sound6URL, sound7URL, sound8URL, sound9URL, sound10URL, sound11URL, sound12URL]

    let randNo = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(allQuestions.list.count)))

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: (soundURLArray[randNo]))
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

I also created a function that responds to the "Answer" that I created in the "Question Bank" file...

When I run the app, the answers seem to be working, but they don't correlate with the sound files that play from the bundle.

Not sure what I'm messing up exactly.

Here's all of my code in my View Controller file for reference:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var feedbackLabel: UILabel!    
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var progressLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIView!


let allQuestions = QuestionBank()
var pickedAnswer: Int?
var questionNumber: Int = 0
var score: Int = 0
var currentQuestion: Question?
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    feedbackLabel.alpha = 0
    progressBar.alpha = 0


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func playButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    playRandomSound()
    feedbackLabel.text = "Listen..."
    feedbackLabel.alpha = 1

}

@IBAction func answerButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {


    if sender.tag == 1 {
        pickedAnswer = 0
    } else if sender.tag == 2 {
        pickedAnswer = 1
    } else if sender.tag == 3 {
        pickedAnswer = 2
    }

    progressBar.alpha = 1

    checkAnswer()

    questionNumber += 1

    nextQuestion()

}

func playRandomSound() {


    let sound1URL = allQuestions.list[0].questionText
    let sound2URL = allQuestions.list[1].questionText
    let sound3URL = allQuestions.list[2].questionText
    let sound4URL = allQuestions.list[3].questionText
    let sound5URL = allQuestions.list[4].questionText
    let sound6URL = allQuestions.list[5].questionText
    let sound7URL = allQuestions.list[6].questionText
    let sound8URL = allQuestions.list[7].questionText
    let sound9URL = allQuestions.list[8].questionText
    let sound10URL = allQuestions.list[9].questionText
    let sound11URL = allQuestions.list[10].questionText
    let sound12URL = allQuestions.list[11].questionText

    let soundURLArray = [sound1URL, sound2URL, sound3URL, sound4URL, sound5URL, sound6URL, sound7URL, sound8URL, sound9URL, sound10URL, sound11URL, sound12URL]

    let randNo = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(allQuestions.list.count)))

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: (soundURLArray[randNo]))
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

}

func updateUI() {

    scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
    progressLabel.text = "Round \(questionNumber) of \(String(allQuestions.list.count))"
    progressBar.frame.size.width = (view.frame.size.width / 12) * CGFloat(questionNumber) //make this dynamic (the 12)
}


func nextQuestion() {

    do{

        updateUI()

            if questionNumber <= allQuestions.list.count - 1 {

            let randNo = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(allQuestions.list.count)))

            currentQuestion = allQuestions.list[randNo]

            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: (currentQuestion!.questionText))

        }

        else {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Game Over", message: "Start Over?", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
            self.startOver()
        })

            alert.addAction(restartAction)

            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }  catch {
        print (error)


    }

}

func startOver() {

    questionNumber = 0
    feedbackLabel.alpha = 0
    score = 0
    progressBar.alpha = 0
    scoreLabel.text = "0"
    progressLabel.text = "0"

}

func checkAnswer() {


    let correctAnswer = currentQuestion?.answer

    if correctAnswer == pickedAnswer {
        feedbackLabel.text = "You Got it! ✔️"

        score += 1

    } else {

        feedbackLabel.text = "Wrong ✖️"
    }
}   
}
```

Thanks immensely for any help!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your playRandomSound function you are setting URLs to objects in the allQuestions.list, which is a list of Question objects. You need to get the .questionText property to get the path. Like so:

```
let sound1URL = allQuestions.list[0].questionText
let sound2URL = allQuestions.list[1].questionText
let sound3URL = allQuestions.list[2].questionText
```

also in your Question class, change:

```
var questionText = Bundle.main.paths(forResourcesOfType: "mp3", inDirectory: "Sounds")
```

to:

```
var questionText: URL
```

and add the following to the init():

```
Bundle.main.url(forResource: text, withExtension: "mp3", subdirectory: "Sounds")
```

At the moment you are setting the questionText to an array of String containing the text passed in to the init.

The new Question class would look like this:

```
class Question {

    var questionText: URL
    let answer: Int

    init(text: String, correctAnswer: Int){
        questionText = Bundle.main.url(forResource: text, withExtension: "mp3", subdirectory: "Sounds")
        answer = correctAnswer
    }
}
```

With regards to your new question, try keeping track of the current Question by setting it the nextQuestion method:

```
if questionNumber <= allQuestions.list.count - 1 {
    let randNo = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(allQuestions.list.count)))
    currentQuestion = allQuestions.list[randNo] //Add this line
    try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: currentQuestion.questionText) //You would no longer need the array of all URLs

}
```

And in the playRandomSound() method replace the soundArray with the same:

```
let randNo = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(allQuestions.list.count)))
currentQuestion = allQuestions.list[randNo]
```

and play the random sound with
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: currentQuestion.questionText)

in stead of the entry in the soundArray

Then in checkAnswer you could have:

```
let correctAnswer = currentQuestion.answer
```

instead of having it based on your questionNumber variable.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. This makes sense, however after implementing this, the same line (try audioPlayer...) inside of playRandomSound is sending the error: "Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'URL'

Comment: In Question, the questionText is var questionText = Bundle.main.paths where is should be Bundle.main.url

Comment: Right, this is where I am also confused... I don't really know how I should set this up.

Comment: Did changing the questionText to Bundle.main.url work?

Comment: I'm trying that now... I'm still getting an error because I had to use Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "mp3", subdirectory: "Sounds"). That makes questionText  = array of Strings and I'm getting 'Cannot convert value of type String to expected element type URL

Comment: Just took another look at your Question class. Looks like you're not setting the questionText properly. Change the init to use the text passed in to get the sound file rather than setting the questionText to an array with the passed text.

Comment: Right on. This sounds good. The problem is: I'm not sure how to do that! Haha. I'm assuming it is simple, but I'm racking my brain trying to figure this part out.

Comment: Thank you!! That helped clear the errors, and I now can see more clearly what you helped me with. Great stuff!! It still seems that the answers aren't corresponding with the sound files that are being called up. I'm wondering what I did wrong this time!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're going for, but it looks like in nextQuestion you are playing a random audio file from the list of Questions but the checkAnswer method checks the answer based on the questionNumber.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. This helped me sort out the problem. You deserve a gold medal! I can't tell you how much I appreciate your help.

Comment: I have one more question about this project - I added it to the top of the post. Thank you!!

Comment: Awesome, I think this is going to work great. The only thing is - when I add "let correctAnswer = currentQuestion.answer" to checkAnswer it can't find currentQuestion because it was declared within the nextQuestion method (I think!)

Comment: Declare currentQuestion at the top of the class and set it in nextQuestion. You'll have to deal a little bit with optionals because you won't be setting currentQuestion on initialization, but it shouldn't be too bad

Comment: Cool, got it. I'll give it a go. I really appreciate all of your help. Too cool. Hopefully you won't see this thread again! (no promises, though, haha)

Comment: ...I'm back again! I'm having problems with the last instruction you gave about declaring currentQuestion and setting it in nextQuestion.  I tried to declare it like let currentQuestion = 0 then in next Question I tried to plug in the line "currentQuestion = allQuestions.list[randNo]" I get the "cannot assign type [Question] to type Int" then the next line "try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: currentQuestion.questionText)" gives me the error "value of type Int has no member questionText     I am not sure where optionals figure into this situation... Thanks!!

Comment: Set var currentQuestion: Question? At the top, and then set it like you did in nextQuestion. When you need to get properties of currentQuestion, you’ll need to unwrap it with ! like currentQuestion!

Comment: Thanks so much. That seemed to work! Believe it to not, the sound files are still not lining up with the answers in the questionBank I have gone through a few times and tries to troubleshoot the added files i.e. making sure that the answers are correct, and  everything s pointing to the right thing, etc. Still having the issue... Not sure if I messed something up along the way? Thanks again - you are a saint!

Comment: Hmm... Not sure why at first glance. Try adding print statements all over the checkAnswer and nextAnswer methods. I'm assuming you are setting the button tags in the storyboard?

Comment: Cool, will do! Thanks again a million times.

Comment: Does it start with the playButtonPressed action? If so, you're starting with a random sound and not saving it. Do the same process you do in nextQuestion. You may even be able to structure it so that you can have only the one nextQuestion method.

Comment: Once again, seems like you may have nailed it down. Now... the hard part - what the heck to do to fix it!

Comment: I added a bit more implementation to my answer. You're basically doing the same thing as the nextQuestion method

Comment: Wow, that did it!! You are the best!!! I'll throw a parade in your honor when this thing gets released.